# If $a,b,c$ be in Arithmetic Progression,

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If $a,b,c$ be in Arithmetic Progression, $b,c,a$ in Harmonic Progression, prove that $c,a,b$ are in Geometric Progression.

My Attempt:
$a,b,c$ are in AP so
$$b=\dfrac {a+c}{2}$$

$b,c,a$ are in HP so
$$c=\dfrac {2ab}{a+b}$$

Multiplying these relations:
$$bc=\dfrac {a+c}{2} \dfrac {2ab}{a+b}$$
$$=\dfrac {2a^2b+2abc}{2(a+b)}$$
$$=\dfrac {2a^2b+2abc}{2a+2b}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a,b,c$ are in arithmetic progression, we get
\begin{align*}
&c-b=b-a\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a = 2b - c\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $b,c,a$ are in harmonic progression, we get
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{b}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a = \frac{bc}{2b-c}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a = \frac{bc}{a}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{a}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, $c,a,b$ are in geometric progression, as was to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a,b,c$ are in AP we have $a=b-x$ and $c=b+x$ for some $x$ and since $b,c,a$ are in HP  we have $$(b+x)(2b-x) = 2(b-x)b$$

Solwing this we get: $x=0$ or $x=3b$. So in the later case we get $a=-2b$ and $c=4b$ and so $$a^2=4b^2= bc$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Eliminate $c$

$$2ab=(a+b)c=(a+b)(2b-a)$$

Simplify to find $$0=a^2+ab-2b^2=(a+2b)(a-b)$$

Comment: what to do after that?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., what can we conclude if the product of two terms is $0$

Comment: Either of one or both terms are 0.

Answer (score 0):

you did everthing right. Now just multiply both sides with the denominator of RHS and simplify.